# How to count how many times a character appears in a string list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to check if a character exists in a string. So `Atom` is the string and `Ch` the character. `name` is a predicate that converts the string in a list of numbers according to the ASCII code.

`find_element` is a predicate that is supposed to be true only if element `X` is part of a list. `C` is a counter that tells us where exactly element `X` was found.

This is the result I am getting:

```
?- exists(prolog,g). [103][112,114,111,108,111,103] false.
```

-------> 103 is the ASCII code of letter "g" and the list `[112,114,111,108,111,103]` is the list that represents the string "prolog". The question `exists(prolog,g)` should have provided a true response.

However the `find_element` predicate is working correctly. I don't understand why this is happening because when I type for example

```
?- find_element(5,[3,4,5,6,5,2],X).
```

I am getting `X= 3 ; X = 5 ; false.`
 ---->

which is absolutely fine because it tells me that 5 is the 3rd and the 5th element of the list.

So the problem is that `find_element` is working when I type something like `?- find_element(5,[3,4,5,6,5,2],X)` but it is not when I try to call the predicate exists (which calls `find_element`).

This is the code:

```
find_element(X,[X|T],1).

find_element(X,[H|T],C):- find_element(X,T,TEMPC), C is TEMPC +1.

exists(Atom,Ch):- name(Atom,[X|T]), name(Ch,Z), write(Z), write([X|T]), find_element(Z,[X|T],Count).
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to check if a character exists in a string. So Atom is the string and Ch the character. name is a predicate that converts the string in a list of numbers according to the ASCII code. find_element is a predicate that is supposed to be true only if element X is part of a list. C is a counter that tells us where is exactly element X was found

Comment: Example: -?exists(prolog,g) true

Comment: ...is there something wrong with this code? Did it fail in some way?

Comment: yes! this is the result i am getting: ?- exists(prolog,g).
[103][112,114,111,108,111,103]
false.
However the find_element predicate is working correctly. I dont understand why this is happening because when i type for example      ?- find_element(5,[3,4,5,6,5,2],X).                                      
I am getting 
X= 3 ; X = 5 ;
false.                      ---->which is absolutely fine because it tells me that 5 istha third and the 5th element of the list.

Comment: Your question is closed, because it didn't contain enough information to answer. If you edit your question to include the additional information you've provided in these comments, it may be reopened and get answers. Use the `edit` link above these comments to do that.

Comment: So the problem is that find_element is working when i type something like that ?- find_element(5,[3,4,5,6,5,2],X) but it is not when i try to call the predicate exists (which calls find_element).

Comment: Thank you. Will do that and reopen the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cleaned a bit your code, and fixed a bug:

```
find_element(X,[X|_], 1).
find_element(X,[_|T], C) :-
    find_element(X,T,TEMPC),
    C is TEMPC +1.

exists(Atom, Ch):-
    name(Atom, L),
    name(Ch, [Z]),
    find_element(Z, L, _Count).
```

note `name(Ch, [Z])` to extract the single character. Now

```
?- exists(pippo,o).
true
```

It's worth to note that

```
?- find_element(3, [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],P).
P = 3 ;
P = 7 ;
false.

?- nth1(P, [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 3).
P = 3 ;
P = 7 ;
false.
```

your find_element/3 behaves as nth1/3, with arguments 1 and 3 swapped.

Of course there are simpler and more general ways to perform such test. Using ISO builtins
like [sub_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5)/5 (a really powerful primitive for atom inspection)

```
?- sub_atom(pippo, _,_,_, o).
true ;
```

or memberchk/2, after the conversion to character lists that you already know (but using ISO builtin [atom_codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_codes/2)/2)

```
exists(Atom, Ch):-
    atom_codes(Atom, L),
    atom_codes(Ch, [Z]),
    memberchk(Z, L).
```

To count occurrences of a sub_atom, library(aggregate) can be used

```
occurences(Atom, Ch, N) :-
  aggregate_all(count, sub_atom(Atom, _,_,_, Ch), N).

?- occurences(pippo, p, X).
X = 3.
```

Comment: +1. By the way, @DanaiTri, if you think an answer is helpful, please remember to upvote it, or mark it as an accepted answer.